# Get all field names in a Django form in python view

Tags: django

How to get all field names in a Django non-model form inside python `views.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the names of fields defined in Django form

`all_fields = FormName.declared_fields.keys()`

Answer (score -2):

```
def view_name(request):
    form_name=nonModelFormName(request.POST);
    all_fields=[f.name for f in form_name];
```

`all_fields` is a list of field names in a Django form

Comment: Why is this posted as an answer?